# Can I run for loop over %files directive in the .spec file?

Tags: rpm, specfile

I am writing a spec file which creates multiple packages. Can I use a for loop over %files directive with different names, like this:

```
for name in {package1, package2, package3} ; do
  %files -n $name
  %attr(644, root, root) /etc/systemd/system/$name.service
done
```

Answer (score 2):

In long words due to minimal post length restriction: No.

Spec files are not any form of scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

Spec file is not scripting language, you still can use your own script file to create file list and feed the list to spec file. From document "[Directives For the %files list](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html)":

> ## -f *<file>* — Read the %files List From *<file>*
>
> The **-f** option is used to direct RPM to read the **%files** list from the named file. Like the
>   **%files** list in a spec file, the file named using the **-f** option should
>   contain one filename per line and also include any of the directives
>   named in this section.
>
> ```
> %files latex -f tetex-latex-skel
> ```
>
> Here, the
>   filenames present in the file tetex-latex-skel would be packaged.

Answer (score 0):

```
%{expand:%(/bin/bash -c "for name in package1 package2 package3; do
cat <<EOF
%files -n \$name
%attr(644, root, root) /etc/systemd/system/\$name.service
EOF
done")}
```